# CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString error codes

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling, clgeocoder

I am working on a project where I use CLGeocoder to determine the placemarks for a particular location.
Very simple call like this.

```
CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(location) { (placemarks, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
```

Instead of printing out the NSError's localizedDescription, I would like to be able to capture the CLError code and respond accordingly.  For example, if the location can't be found, my localizedDescription prints

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 8.)
```

How can I, in Swift determine the CLError code so that I do not have to switch on some localized description that will change based on user's locale?
Can this be done?
I only have a couple of cases that I want to switch on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the error as `CLError` and then switch the error `code`:

```
if let error = error as? CLError { 
    switch error.code {
    case .locationUnknown:
        print("locationUnknown: location manager was unable to obtain a location value right now.")
    case .denied:
        print("denied: user denied access to the location service.")
    case .promptDeclined:
        print("promptDeclined: user didn’t grant the requested temporary authorization.")
    case .network:
        print("network: network was unavailable or a network error occurred.")
    case .headingFailure:
        print("headingFailure: heading could not be determined.")
    case .rangingUnavailable:
        print("rangingUnavailable: ranging is disabled.")
    case .rangingFailure:
        print("rangingFailure: a general ranging error occurred.")
    default : break
    }
}
```